# Feynman Two Loop Integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory

Is there any reference suitable for a beginner that you recommend for learning two loop integrals evaluation by hand ( and/or some package) that you know of?

Comment: Just to clarify -- when you say "beginner", do you mean that you haven't done a 2 loop integral, but you have been through a QFT course and done 1 loop calculations?

Comment: The tree level calculations are understood to a considerable extent, that I meant. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: If you've never done a 1-loop calculation and worked through renormalization, I would start there. Renormalization is very difficult conceptually, and it is much easier to understand in the context of 1 loop diagrams, which are computationally simpler than 2 loops (though, not easy!). There is nothing really conceptually new about 2 loop diagrams, but Feynman diagrams become technically much more difficult to compute as you increase the number of loops. A standard QFT book like Srednicki or Peskin and Schroeder will cover 1 loop and renormalization.

Comment: This paper maybe gives a taste of the relative level of technical complexity of different loop orders: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0307297

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew.